Movie with a beautiful lesbian scene?
I've seen part of this movie in TV once (long ago).
I don't want to tie myself down but I think movie year is around 90s/2000+.
I remember pretty much just the one most memorable scene:

two girls having lesbian fun time in bed during day

I remember it to be artistically beautiful (great lighting, light from the window in the background, a lot of orange colors etc.)

it isn't porn, softcore at most
I also think it was playing in some kind of (residential, rural) school

drama, about transition to adulthood

ok, another detail to the quality: it wasn't a "bad" movie, might as well be Hollywood
I've seen it in Germany, but can't say it to be a German movie

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!
Edit:

another girl (sharing the same room) watched/heard the two girls have their private time (100% sure)
birds might have been involved (in the movie)
hot candidate: Lost and Delirious


Anything you remember about the actresses in the scene? Plot? Genre/Theme other than drama? Lesbian couples in boarding schools in movies are more common than you'd think.

If you found the answer, post it as an answer and accept it rather than updating the question.

Lost and Delirious

Found it by myself at a bottom of this list.
